# javascript code not working in JSF xhtml page

Tags: javascript

Here is the running code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLTat/40/)
You will see that It is working perfectly fine here but when I run this code in eclipse using glassfish server 3.2.1 in a xhtml page then it gives this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /MasterPage/MiDASMaster.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 135] Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "class".
```

Here is the code of xhtml page(exactly same like fiddle) I tried it on Jsbin as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.highlight {
    background:yellow;
}
.removeHighlight {
    background:green;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

            function test(){
        alert(document.getElementById("divId"));
         var regex = new RegExp('this',"gi");
         document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML     
         =document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) 
        {
            return '<span class=\'highlight\'>' + matched + '</span>';
        });


    }



</script>

<div id="divId">

    This is the text This is the text This is the text This is the text 
    This is the text This is the text This is the the text
</div>
```

..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XHTML is probably malformed.

Put your Javascript code into a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        alert("Your javascript here");
    ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: CData section? can you please elaborate

Comment: CData has removed the error but now the function `test()` is not calling

Comment: @viki that's a different problem and would be a different question. Your original problem is solved now. Feel free to ask another question once you have investigated some research in this new problem you are facing.

Comment: Sure :) I have posted my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445497/unable-to-call-js-function) please see

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit that why it was not working without CData.As I am new to JS so It would be really informative for me