# Unable to call test()

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. [This is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLTat/41/) with my code.

If I remove `CDATA` then it works fine on fiddle but create issue on XHTML editors like eclipse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
<![CDATA[
  function test() {
      alert(document.getElementById("divId"));
      var regex = new RegExp('this',"gi");
      document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML
      = document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML.replace(regex, 
            function(matched) 
            {
                return '<span class=\'highlight\'>' + matched + '</span>';
            });
  }
]]>
```

here is the `<div>` in question:

```
<div id="divId">
    This is the text This is the text This is the text This is the text 
    This is the text This is the text This is the the text
</div>
```

and I am unable to call `test()` function. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "unable" mean? Do you get errors? How did you call it?

Comment: My suggestion?  Stop using xHTML (especially Transitional) and switch to HTML5.  You won't need that ugly CDATA comment notation, for starters. ;)

Comment: by unable I mean functio is not calling.i didn't find any error

Comment: @LightStyle `newline in the HTML reassignment` .. where I am adding this?  I am new to JS so please guide a bit precisly.Thanks :)

Comment: Don't worry, it is not the problem, as many pointed out

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `test()`?

Comment: @DerekHenderson Its my Bad.please see code again I have edited .. I am calling it at the end on button `<input type="submit" value="highlight the text" onclick="test()" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just comment CDATA lines :

```
...
// <![CDATA[
...
// ]]>
```

Comment: I cant comment as I mentioned in my question .. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443461/javascript-code-not-working-in-jsf-xhtml-page/17443517?noredirect=1#comment25340917_17443517

Comment: @viki you can. Those comments are only for javascript, the XML parser still recognises the CDATA section.

Comment: @viki out of curiosity, did you even read the [Wikipedia article about CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) I linked in my [last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17443517/1328300) of your previous question? It explicitly [shows the usage of it in XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Use_of_CDATA_in_program_output). Please make sure you **understand** why it works that way.

Comment: @guy777 Can you please elaborate a little bit that it was not working without commenting it? I am new to JS so It would be really informative for me :) thanks

Comment: @viki [Maybe we should have a chat about that topic](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32815/chat-with-viki)

Comment: @viki if you don't comment CDATA lines, the Javascript interpreter read those lines, and it's not Javascript !!!

Answer (score 3):

Enclose  between /* */ like this

```
 /*<![CDATA[*/

            function test(){
        alert(document.getElementById("divId"));
         var regex = new RegExp('this',"gi");
         document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML     
         =document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) 
        {
            return '<span class=\'highlight\'>' + matched + '</span>';
        });


    }

/*]]>*/
```